# js.erb files with esbuild in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, sprockets, stimulusjs, esbuild

I would like to package a js.erb file with esbuild.
In my app, a user clicks on a 'Buy' button, which is connected to a Stimulus controller. The Stimulus action redirects to Stripe, but needs a public key. I want to read that key from the Rails credentials at esbuild-time, rather than hard-cding it into the js-file. Akin to

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  redirect(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();

    const stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:public] %>");

    stripe.redirectToCheckout({...});
}
```

My esbuild line in package.json:

```
 "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds",
```

I tried without success

```
Sprockets.register_mime_type 'application/javascript', extensions: ['.js.erb']
```

Comment: FYI: The esbuild error: [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".erb" files: app/javascript/controllers/stripe_checkout_controller.js.erb

Comment: Edit the question to add the information, don't add it in a comment.  Comments are not permanent.